# Can photon be said to warp time only and not space? Can SR be modelled like GR, considering warping of temporal dimension only?

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, photons, spacetime, dark-matter

If we try to get closer and closer to a photon (i.e. get closer to speed of light), time slows down in a fashion similar to when we get closer and closer to a massive object. Are these two things related somehow?

Following up on this, can we say the following:

- Normal matter -> bends both space and time
- Photons -> bends time only
- Dark matter -> bends space only

It is said that dark matter does not interact with electromagnetism, but has mass. Can this be because dark matter bends space only, while photons bend time only and hence they somehow can't interact?

Comment: This question currently has some close votes with the "non-mainstream" close reason. I think that's a mistake. We use the non-mainstream close reason to shut down discussion like "what if the world worked like X?", because such questions tend to become moving targets as X evolves through different types of impossibility. But here we have a question "*does* the world work like X?" This seems like a legitimate question about mainstream general relativity, even though the answer happens to be "no." I think one shouldn't need to know the answer to a question to know whether it is on-topic.

Comment: @rob I disagree with your point of view.  If the question is "does the world work like X" , where X is contrary to mainstream Physics, there there is no real difference with "what if the world worked like X?". It becomes just a rhetoric   nuance of the same approach. I would like to stress that the opening statement "getting close and closer to a photon" is completely outside any known theory or experiment. Don't you think this is enough to classify as non-mainstream Physics? I agree with your last sentence. I do not think this question is on-topic.

Comment: @GiorgioP It's fine if we have different perspectives here, though a policy debate should go on [meta]. I wasn't sure what "getting closer to a photon" meant, and considered at least three options. Of course you can never "catch up" to a photon, although that's a nontrivial result of relativity which surprises some students. But it's sometimes useful to think of ways that a particle becomes "photon-like" in the limit $E\gg mc^2$. I chose the interpretation provided in the question, "as speed approaches $c$," which is solidly the subject of special relativity. Hanlon's Razor should apply.

Answer (score 1):

Nope photons doesn't just bend time only. It bends, very bad word, space also for example radiation dominated universe (FRW metric). Why? Cause photon has an associated $T_{\mu\nu}$ which tells us how $g_{\mu\nu}$ changes, or in sloppy language how's space time bends. Same goes for dark matter.

Comment: Radiation (kinetic energy $\gg$ mass) doesn’t bend spacetime. For example, a relativistic bullet doesn’t become a black hole or deflect light, even if its kinetic energy exceeds the Schwarzschild limit. So photons in flight don’t bend spacetime. It is a common misconception. More technically, the gravitational field of the photon’s energy is canceled out by the gravitomsgnetism of its movement.

Comment: @safesphere Do photons not enter the EM tensor in any way? How come they don't constitute energy/momentum flux? Also when you say "photons *in flight* don't bend spacetime", are there situations where photons do?

Comment: @Charlie Yes. Spacetime is bent by the energy of interactions, e.g. by the events of emission and absorption of photons. Again, a relativistic bullet doesn’t bend spacetime. This is very easy to see, because its energy is frame dependent while the scalar spacetime curvature is not. Yet if two such bullets collide, they might form a black hole.

Comment: @safesphere Ah I see what you mean now about the bullet, it sounds analogous to how a decay cannot form heavier particles but a collision can, because the system as a whole can't have vanishing kinetic energy in any frame, thanks for explaining.

Comment: @Charlie The stress energy tensor of matter is an approximation, a sum of contributions of many particles. When they constantly interact, we get the statistical sum, because the contribution of the gravitomagnetism averages out to zero. However, when particles don’t interact, the gravitomagnetism of each particle of radiation cancels out the contribution of this particle to the tensor.

Comment: @safesphere Ah I haven't studied the intersection of GR and EM yet so I'm a little lost on the details, but I will keep this in mind.

Comment: @Charlie gravitomagnetism does not refer to electromagnetism, but to the gravitational field of a moving object (roughly the gravity of momentum as opposed to the gravity of energy). A small static bullet doesn’t have a noticeable field. Yet in a relativistic frame the energy of the bullet is big and must in principle curve spacetime.  This contradiction is resolved by the gravitomagnetism canceling out the contribution of the kinetic energy.

Comment: @safesphere Ahh I see what you mean now.

Answer (score 1):

Let us take the different concepts appearing here apart and see if it answers your question. First of all general relativity (GR) is a generalization of special relativity (SR), the main difference being that in GR the space-time (notice they are pasted together, they are *one* thing) is curved by **energy** (Check Einstein field equations). Both SR and GR are built over the idea that frames of reference are connected by Lorentz transformations instead of Galilean transformations, in other words the speed of light is implemented as the speed limit of the Universe (for anything).

Under this view we can now group the things you mention. Matter, photons and dark matter all have energy, they are just different presentations if you will, but to all of them we can associate an energy density, therefore they **all** curve (space-time). The question is how much. How much they curve space-time depends on their masses (or energy densities more formally). So if you are speaking about a single photon, you can very likely neglect the curvature in your problem (exceptions may occur depending on the relevant scales). Same goes for matter, you need large amounts of it though to curve space-time, like the amount in a Start or a Black-hole to witness any affect of curvature.

Dark matter is a more subtle topic, but one thing we know and it is that it has mass and interacts gravitationally just like matter does. So in terms of curvature it has the same effects. Historically it is exactly this behaviour that lead the community to coin the name Dark matter since, we can observe its gravitational effects, so it must be some sort of matter, but just can't see with light, thus "Dark".

So you cannot get "closer and closer" to a photon, the photon is playing no role. You can't just travel at the speed of light (while having a rest mass), without investing infinite energy accelerating to that speed.

All in all, the message really is space and time are "glued" together, nothing "bends" just one of them. I suggest you try to look at the mathematical details if possible to understand what a *metric* (in GR) means and then study what *space-time intervals* are.

Answer (score 0):

The premiss of the question is flawed. Time does not slow down as you approach the speed of light because you cannot approach the speed of light. No matter how you move inertially, spacetime appears the same to you, in particular: light moves at $c$ in all directions, which means: you cannot approach the speed of light.

With 2 frames of reference, velocity makes sense, but each observer sees the other's clock tick slower, which is described in the usual manner with titled hyper-*planes* of simultaneity.